# Docker Desktop (Windows): Container not receiving UDP traffic from network

Tags: windows, docker, network-programming, udp

I have a container set up to listen to traffic in the UDP port 6789 of my wi-fi IP address (192.168.200.18) and an external device sending info to 192.168.200.18:6789/udp.

I can see using `netstat -ap UDP` that my computer is listening on that port. I have checked with [UDP Test Tool](https://udp-test-tool.informer.com) that I am indeed receiving the packets. However, the packets never make their way into the container.

The container is connected to a docker network created within the .yaml file with

```
networks:
  mynetwork:
    name: mynetwork
    driver: bridge
```

In the compose.yaml file I'm using to run the container I included the following instructions to open/redirect ports and connect to the docker network.

```
ports:
  - "192.168.200.18:6789:6789/udp"

networks:
  - mynetwork
```

If I copy the docker run command from Docker Desktop there are `-p 192.168.200.18:6789:6789/udp` and `--network=mynetwork` options in there. So it appears there's nothing wrong with the setup. But I still don't receive any packet in the containers.

This is also deployed in a remote virtual machine where it works fine, I assume the issue is somewhere in the network setup of my work laptop, but I can't figure out what could be causing the problem.